# Laravel :How to search for item from the main page search bar

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a search bar on my master page. All other pages are extending this page. 
I have a search text field on the master page which is defined as such

```
{{Form::open(array('action'=>'TopicsController@searchquery', 'method'=>'GET'))}}      
    {{Form::input('search', 'q', null, ['placeholder'=>'Search', 'class' => 'search'])}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

The Routes.php entry is as follows :

```
Route::get('/searchquery/{q}', [
    'uses'=> 'TopicsController@searchquery',
    'as' => 'topic.searchquery']);
```

and the Controller action looks like this

```
    public function searchquery($q)
{

    if($search = Request::get('q')){

        $topics = Topic::search($search);
    }
    else {
        $topics = Topic::all();
    }

    $categories = Category::all();
    $tags = $this->topicRepo->allTags();
    return View::make('topics.topicSearch')->withCategories($categories)->withTopics($topics)->with('term', $q)->withTags($tags);

}
```

However when I perform the search , the search query in the controller's searchquery is not getting the correct parameter.
My URL look like this : `http://localhost:8000/searchquery/%7Bq%7D?q=test`

Please Help.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to remove the `/{q}` from the route definition, now it should work fine. But I guess you want it have the pretty way, `/q/term`, not like `?q=term`. Well, you're not getting that with normal HTML form submit, but with a little JS you can make it so:

```
// jQuery, but it can be done without it
$('form').submit(function() {
  document.location.href = '/searchquery/' + $(this).find('input').val();
  return false;
 });
```

If you opted for the last solution, you can consider not hard-coding the route in the JS code, instead, you can set the route in an data attribute (e.g. `data-submit-url`) on the form.

Comment: I was wondering if using query params would be the way forward for me . that is what I was planning to do..